Price fetching from csv in python
I have an input csv file (top_10_stocks.csv) which has list of top 10 stocks for every month since October 2016 based on a strategy i have developed. The idea is to generate the list of these top 10 stocks every end of the month and when the stock doesn't occur in the month, exit it on the first trading day of following month. To test this I am trying to generate an output csv file using python which can give exit date and price for against the entry date.
Suppose A stock ABC appeared in the list in October 16, Nov 16, Dec 16 And then it doesn't occur in Jan 17, then I must exit on first trading session closing in Feb.
my script to genrate backtesting out put file is as follows:
import pandas as pd

# Load the sorted output ranked file
input_file_excel = 'top_10_stocks.xlsx'  # Path to your input Excel file
nifty50_data_file = 'nifty50_stock_data.csv'  # Path to your CSV file containing stock data

# Load the top 10 stocks data
top_stocks_data = pd.read_excel(input_file_excel)

# Load Nifty 50 stock data
nifty50_data = pd.read_csv(nifty50_data_file)

# Ensure the date columns are in datetime format
top_stocks_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(top_stocks_data['Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')  # Specify the format
nifty50_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(nifty50_data['Date'])

# Create a new DataFrame to hold the results
results_list = []  # Use a list to collect results

# Track currently held stocks and their entry dates
held_stocks = {}

# Iterate through each month in the top stocks data
unique_months = top_stocks_data['Month'].unique()
for month in unique_months:
    # Filter stocks that appeared in the current month
    stocks_in_month = top_stocks_data[top_stocks_data['Month'] == month]

    # Check stocks held from the previous months
    for stock in list(held_stocks.keys()):
        if stock in stocks_in_month['Symbol'].values:
            continue  # Still held, skip it (it is still in top 10)
        else:
            # The stock is no longer in the top 10, record the exit details
            exit_month = month  # This is the last month the stock appeared
            exit_date = nifty50_data[nifty50_data['Date'] > held_stocks[stock]['Entry Date']]['Date'].min()

            if exit_date is not pd.NaT:  # Check if there is a valid exit date
                # Find the first trading day of the next month after the last occurrence
                next_month = pd.to_datetime(f"{exit_month}-01") + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1)
                exit_date = nifty50_data[nifty50_data['Date'] == next_month]['Date'].min()

                # Get exit price
                exit_price_row = nifty50_data[nifty50_data['Date'] == exit_date]
                if not exit_price_row.empty:
                    exit_price = exit_price_row['Last Close'].values[0]

                    # Append the stock's details to results_list
                    results_list.append({
                        'Symbol': stock,
                        'Entry Date': held_stocks[stock]['Entry Date'],
                        'Entry Price': held_stocks[stock]['Entry Price'],
                        'Exit Date': exit_date,
                        'Exit Price': exit_price
                    })

            # Remove the stock from held stocks as it no longer appears in the top 10
            del held_stocks[stock]

    # Update held stocks for the current month
    for _, row in stocks_in_month.iterrows():
        stock = row['Symbol']
        if stock not in held_stocks:
            held_stocks[stock] = {
                'Entry Date': row['Date'],
                'Entry Price': row['Last Close']
            }

# Convert results_list to a DataFrame
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results_list)

# Save the results to a new Excel file
results_df.to_excel('final_stocks_with_exit_prices.xlsx', index=False)

print(f"Final stocks with entry and exit prices saved to: final_stocks_with_exit_prices.xlsx")

I fetched the excel file (nifty50_stock_data) having everyday closing data of my stock universe. and i tried to get exit price corresponding to exit date from this file but it doesn't help Even the exit date is not calculated correctly. Tried using chatGpt as well but it doesn't help.
you can access all files here.
How to resolve this?

Once you convert the CSV to a dataframe, this becomes a pandas question. The original CSV is irrelevant.

Can you provide an example of what the desired output is?

Oh okay. I would keep that in mind.

Is there a concrete "first issue" we can help resolve? Maybe something like "Why is my exit_date not calculated correctly?" At the moment this feels like there are potentially lots of problems rather than one.

@JonSG Hi, I am not able to code the logic where I can identify the exit date.

@Yolkions updated the output image in the same folder.

you are unlikely to get the level of ad-hoc help given the amount of 'stuff' tyou hope/expect folks to trawl through. suggest you read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and rethink/post your challenge
